# Limit image gallery selected images to 5 maximum in wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress

im using native wordpress image uploader in my website front end so the user can upload images to the website.

what i want to do is limit the photos selection only to 5 nothing more

like this

[image]

when the user try to select more, i want to stop him.

here is my code i got so far and it's working fine except it allow user to select unlimited images

```
       <ul class="product_images">
            <?php
            $gallery = explode( ',', $product_images );

            if ( $gallery ) {
                foreach ($gallery as $image_id) {
                    if ( empty( $image_id ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );
                    ?>
                    <li class="image" data-attachment_id="<?php echo $image_id; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $attachment_image[0]; ?>" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>

        <input type="hidden" id="product_image_gallery" name="product_image_gallery" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_images ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an old answer but you could try the code from this link, technically it should work.
[WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-can-you-limit-the-number-of-images-videos-that-can-be-uploaded-to-a-wordpr)

If it works then you will need to change the number of allowed images like this:

```
  if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
    if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>4)
      $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than five (5) image.";
  }
```